# Flyway support to re-run SQL file multiple times using placeholder params

Tags: flyway

Does FlywayDB support the use-case where a script can be re-run multiple times using different parameter sets through "placeholder" and be treated either as separate versions or repeatable migration (though with different SQL files)?  I have a requirement where we'd want to run the same set of scripts to organize data according to "regions" (US, UK, CA, etc.)

e.g...

Files:

```
sql/V1__customer_info.sql
sql/V2__customer_address.sql
```

Commands:

```
# Migrate US customers
mvn -Dflyway.placeholders.region_id=us flyway:migrate

# Migrate UK customers
mvn -Dflyway.placeholders.region_id=uk flyway:migrate

# Migrate Australian customers
mvn -Dflyway.placeholders.region_id=au flyway:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

No is the short answer. I have had a couple of ideas you might like to explore further:

1. Implement it in a [callback](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks) specifically `afterMigrate.sql` and then call as per your example. afterMigrate is called even if there are no pending migrations to apply. This is "extending" the callback feature and you would be constrained by a single sql file so would need to combine info and address into a single file. [Java callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/hooks#callsbacks) are more flexible however I have not used them.
2. Pass a list into the placeholder and have your database split and loop over it. This would be achievable with Oracle and PLSQL but may be tricky with other databases or if you need to support multiple database types.